# Selecting "all" friends in edit friends

Tags: facebook

Under accounts, edit friends, Facebook chooses "most recent interacted with" and will not let me change it to "all" friends. When I change it to "all" it resets back to "most recently interacted with", and this is not what I desire. My other friends are having the same problem. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Hi, this isn't the Facebook support page. Please use http://www.facebook.com/help/?ref=drop

Comment: It is working for me.  Did you try a different browser?

Comment: I think this no longer applies. As of late september, the **Edit friends** is no longer available. You just go to your profile, click **Friends** and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

With the new Facebook [Timeline](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline) (coming at the end of this month) and other UI changes, you can see all your friends at

> facebook.com/**username**?sk=friends

or

> facebook.com/**profile.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx**&sk=friends

depending if you have o username set or just the profile id.

Comment: This is available even without _Timeline_. I think it's the new default behavior for _friends_.